# Vue + TypeScript prop type error: "'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and the Vue Composition API and I find the following error confusing:

I have a component which takes as a prop an `api` variable which should be an `AxiosInstance`:

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    api: AxiosInstance,
(...)
```

But when I try to set the `type` of the prop to be `AxiosInstance`, I get the following error:

> TS2693: 'AxiosInstance' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
> value here.

This is confusing to me, because my impression is that I'm using types as the values in this kind of prop object.  For example, I have another prop defined as follows:

```
    fileExtensionFilter: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined
    },
```

How do I properly define the type of this `api` prop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the solution from a coworker:

When using `defineComponent()`, you need to use Vue's `PropType` helper, described in the docs [here](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#proptype-t).

So the code should look like this:

```
import {PropType} from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    api: Object as PropType<AxiosInstance>,
(...)
```